# Why composer updates all existent deps?

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I added a new bundle dependency to my composer.json file and when running composer update command, the composer updates all existent deps while I just want to install the new bundle.
Is there a command option to install just the new deps without updating existent ones ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#update)

In order to get the latest versions of the dependencies and to update the composer.lock file, you should use the update command.

```
php composer.phar update
```

This will resolve all dependencies of the project and write the exact versions into composer.lock.

**If you just want to update a few packages and not all**, you can list them as such:

```
php composer.phar update vendor/package vendor/package2
```

You can also use wildcards to update a bunch of packages at once:

```
php composer.phar update vendor/*
```

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a command option to install just the new deps without updating existant ones?

Yes, there is: [`composer require`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#require).

Simply run `composer require vendor/package`.

Comment: This is my favourite way to add new packages because I don't have to fiddle with the JSON source code. Additionally, this will only fetch the package version that best fits into the already existing versions, and if I choose a version that conflicts with existing packages, Composer will deny adding that package instead of getting into an unresolvable dependency state.